# Adding checkboxInput to RShiny

Tags: r, if-statement, web-applications

I'm really new to using RShiny and I'm struggling to add a Checkbox. There are a few stages to the task I've been given but I'm currently stuck on this step. My aim currently is to create a webapp which displays a boxplot graph with the x-axis (categorical) and y-axis (numerical) variables being dependent on a selectInput. So far I've gotten this to work but now I need to add a checkbox such that when it is clicked on, the boxplots split up into separate plots by categorical level. I've tried a few variations of code but I'm not really getting anywhere and the best I've come up with I think is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- penguins[,-2]

colnames(data) <- c("Species",
                    "Bill Length (mm)",
                    "Bill Depth (mm)", 
                    "Flipper Length (mm)",
                    "Body Mass (g)",
                    "Sex",
                    "Year")

data.numeric <- data[, c(2:5, 7)]

data.categorical <- data[, c(1,6)]



ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Penguin boxplots"),
  selectInput("ycol", 
              "Numeric Variable", 
              names(data.numeric),
              selected = names(data.numeric)[3]),
  selectInput("xcol",
              "Categorical Variable",
              names(data.categorical),
              selected = names(data.categorical)[2]),
  checkboxInput("split",
                "Split Levels",
                value = FALSE),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  ))



server <- function(input, output){
  reactive({ if (input$split){
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      selectedData <- reactive({
        data[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
      })
      plot(selectedData())
    })
  } else {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      par(mar = c(20, 4.1, 0, 1))
      selectedData <- reactive({
        data[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
      })
      plot(selectedData())
    })
  }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**as you'll see, the code here isn't intended to actually split the graphs up, it's just there for me to be able to test the code until I can get the if and else statements working - then i'll facet the plots appropriately. So really, my issue is getting the if and else statement to work.**

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks folks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for `server`.

I would recommend avoiding nesting `output` and `reactive` expressions inside other `reactive` expressions, and duplicating `output$plot1`.

Instead, you can simplify, and include an if/else inside your `renderPlot` to show different visualizations depending on checkbox. I added a bit to demonstrate differences in plotting with different checkbox states.

Certainly, additional `reactive` expressions could be helpful, depending on what else you may want to include in your app.

**Edit**: Replaced plot with `ggplot` `geom_boxplot` and uses `facet_wrap`.

```
server <- function(input, output){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    selectedData <- data[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    if (input$split) {
      ggplot(data = selectedData, aes(y = .data[[input$ycol]])) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        facet_wrap(~.data[[input$xcol]])
    } else {
      ggplot(data = selectedData, aes(x = .data[[input$xcol]], y = .data[[input$ycol]])) +
        geom_boxplot()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this will help a lot. 

I'm now trying to use ggplot & facetwrap instead but I get the error: *'Error: could not find the function "selectedData"**


The code I've written looks like this:

server <- function(input, output){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    selectedData <- data[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    if (input$split) {
      ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        facet_wrap(~input$xcol)
    } else {
      plot(selectedData)
    }
  })
}


Do you know why it won't work?

Comment: Yeah that's sorted it now so I should hopefully be able to keep going on now. Thanks so much